# After representing relationships in an ER diagram, how are they then illustrated when creating tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship, create-table, erd

In numerous sources that attempt to describe the process of creating ER diagrams for future Databases I’ve seen many different types of relationships. Some of them have attributes attached to them and some do not. After completing the ER diagram and proceeding to write the SQL statements that are responsible for creating the tables that will hold the data, how are the relationships represented within these create table statements?

For example, an entity and its corresponding attributes are represented through the use of the create table statement.

Are relationships represented through the use of these create table statements too?

Do they get their own create table statement?

What is the difference between a relationship with attributes and a relationship without attributes, and how is this difference represented in how the tables are created for the data that needs to be stored?

Comment: This is a kind of one question per 'question' kind of forum

Answer (score 0):

ER Diagram represents DB entities and relations between them. To create entities with SQL, you use `CREATE TABLE` statements, relations are represented with *foreign keys*. For example, the following ER Diagram,

[image: ERD]

can be represented with the SQL code below:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE student (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  group_id INTGER references group(id)
);
```